# Calling API from SQL Server [Issue]

Tags: sql-server, api, t-sql

**I am working with API and MSSQL.** I need to call an API from SQL Server. But On execution, its response is null. Can anyone list errors if some in the queries?

The API responds but the issue is it shows error in Authentication while I'm using exact correct credentials. It's a POST API.

This is the only way I found correct on browsing the whole a day on Google. Can someone help or list errors?

```
DECLARE @authHeader NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
DECLARE @contentType NVARCHAR(64) = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
DECLARE @appVersion NVARCHAR(20) = '3.2.1'
DECLARE @appkey NVARCHAR(50) = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
DECLARE @deviceId NVARCHAR(50) = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
DECLARE @deviceType int = 1;
DECLARE @language int = 1;
DECLARE @status NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @statusText NVARCHAR(32);

DECLARE @Body as VARCHAR(8000) = 
'{
    "itemId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "itemType":XXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    "liked":"true"
}'

DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(2000);
DECLARE @token INT;
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(256) = 'https://api-stage.testapp.com/v4/test';

    Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP', @token OUT;

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'POST', @url, 'false'

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authentication', @authHeader

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'appVersion', @appVersion

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'appkey', @appkey

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'deviceId', @deviceId

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'devicetype', @deviceType

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'language', @language

    EXEC sp_OAMethod @token, 'send', null

    Exec sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestBody', null, 'Body', @body

    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
    EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;

    PRINT 'Status: ' + @status + ' (' + @statusText + ')';
    PRINT 'Response text: ' + @responseText;

    Select @ResponseText as Response
```

Comment: Send method is called before seting the request body

Comment: By far the best approach to take is to not do this from SQL Server. As you've noticed, troubleshooting is hard that way. It's also easy to introduce resource leaks (as this code does, as there is no `sp_OADestroy`) and generally make your server less scalable. Implement this in client code. This doesn't need to be hard; a simple `Invoke-RestMethod` from PowerShell could do (scheduled as a job if need be). Leave SQL Server to SQL, which is what it's good at; not HTTP, which it's not good at.